# How to check if "Use GPS-provided time" is selected in "Automatic date & time" programmatically?

Tags: java, android, datetime, gps-time

I have a device with Android 7 that has "Use GPS-provided time" option in "Automatic date & time". I use this code to know if "Automatic date & time" vale

```
android.provider.Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0);
```

- "Use network-provided time" returns 1.
- "Use GPS-provided time" returns 0.
- "Off" returns 0.

So 0 value has 2 meanings. How can I know if "Use GPS-provided time" is selected?

Comment: Hi Jon, have you already found a solution?

Comment: I haven't been able to fix the problem.